# How to use Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DevicePicker with Prism (MVVM)?

Tags: c#, mvvm, bluetooth, uwp, prism

I am working on a new UWP application that interacts with some hardware via Bluetooth. Using the [windows-universal-samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) as a guide I was able to sucessfully get what I wanted working.

Now I am trying to refactor the code I wrote in a click event handler into a view model class using Prism. However I don't know how to approach this. In other scenarios where I need to pass data between a View and ViewModel I would create a property on the ViewModel and bind it to the control in the view's XAML.

The problem is that `Windows.Devices.Enumaration.DevicePicker` is used in a way that doesn't seem compatible with the MVVM pattern. In the click handler, the data and control are merged together and I don't see how I can make some kind of list property on the view model and then bind it to the view. Here is the simplest example of the code I am working with:

```
async void DiscoverButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var devicePicker = new DevicePicker();
    devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));

    // Calculate the position to show the picker (right below the buttons)
    var ge = DiscoverButton.TransformToVisual(null);
    var point = ge.TransformPoint(new Point());
    var rect = new Rect(point, new Point(100, 100));
    var device = await devicePicker.PickSingleDeviceAsync(rect);

    var bluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
}
```

See `PickSingleDeviceAsync()` creates a control directly.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If you have any other concern regarding this issue, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to abandon the built in UI provided by `DevicePicker` and instead create my own UI to use with `DeviceWatcher`. For example:

```
void StartWatcher()
{
    ResultCollection.Clear();

    string selector = BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector();

    DeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(selector);

    DeviceWatcher.Added += async (deviceWatcher, deviceInformation) =>
    {
        await OnUiThread(() =>
        {
            ResultCollection.Add(deviceInformation);
        });
    };

    DeviceWatcher.Start();
}
```

Where `ResultCollection` would be bound from the view model to the view.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I am trying to refactor the code I wrote in a click event handler into a view model class using Prism. However I don't know how to approach this.

You could bind command for your button and use CommandParameter to pass parameter to the command.

Please refer to the following code sample for details:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="device" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btn}"></Button>
```

```
public class MianViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MianViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ClickedMethod);
    }

    private async void ClickedMethod(object obj)
    {
        var devicePicker = new DevicePicker();
        devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));

        // Calculate the position to show the picker (right below the buttons)
        Button DiscoverButton = obj as Button;
        if (DiscoverButton != null)
        {
            var ge = DiscoverButton.TransformToVisual(null);
            var point = ge.TransformPoint(new Point());
            var rect = new Rect(point, new Point(100, 100));
            var device = await devicePicker.PickSingleDeviceAsync(rect);

            if (device != null)
            {
                var bluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```